# How can I connect to MongoDB on my Mac OSX from a process on a Vagrant/Virtualbox machine?

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, vagrant, netstat

I can't use `localhost` because from my virtual machine's perspective `localhost` is the virtual machine itself and not the underlying host that it is running on.  How can I connect to the host machine from the virtual machine?

I tried this answer to a related question: https://superuser.com/a/310745/157900 but I can't decipher the output from `netstat -rn`.  My output looks like:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            172.28.0.1         UGSc           34        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             23   636160     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
172.28/24          link#4             UCS            20        0     en0
172.28.0.1/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
172.28.0.1         0:14:a9:69:86:d9   UHLWIir        36       24     en0   1190
172.28.0.31        a4:4e:31:19:89:58  UHLWI           0        3     en0   1088
172.28.0.32        74:e5:43:6:1e:f7   UHLWI           0        8     en0   1040
172.28.0.47        f0:db:e2:e5:f1:ad  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1142
172.28.0.57        78:3a:84:a:c3:2b   UHLWI           0        0     en0    701
172.28.0.63        88:1f:a1:2:fc:16   UHLWI           0        0     en0   1200
172.28.0.66        78:31:c1:be:da:46  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1148
172.28.0.70        64:76:ba:8d:b1:32  UHLWI           0        0     en0    854
172.28.0.73        78:31:c1:bb:7:3e   UHLWI           0        0     en0    995
172.28.0.83/32     link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
172.28.0.90        2c:d0:5a:44:b0:6d  UHLWI           0       14     en0   1166
172.28.0.97        30:59:b7:10:5f:ea  UHLWIi          1        1     en0   1175
172.28.0.133       70:56:81:b9:b:3f   UHLWI           0        0     en0   1095
172.28.0.137       a4:4e:31:1c:92:4c  UHLWI           0        6     en0    976
172.28.0.138       90:72:40:90:57:b6  UHLWI           0        0     en0    963
172.28.0.152       b8:e8:56:10:bb:16  UHLWIi          1        0     en0   1106
172.28.0.157       a4:4e:31:1b:98:14  UHLWI           0       50     en0   1089
172.28.0.167       7c:d1:c3:e0:9d:77  UHLWI           0        0     en0    521
172.28.0.175       68:96:7b:49:c7:89  UHLWI           0        0     en0    456
172.28.0.212       18:f6:43:4a:ee:8f  UHLWI           0        0     en0     21
172.28.0.229       7c:e9:d3:f6:3f:c8  UHLWI           0       51     en0   1136
172.28.0.255       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en0
192.168.33         link#11            UC              2        0 vboxnet
192.168.33.1       a:0:27:0:0:1       UHLWIi          1       62     lo0
192.168.33.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1 vboxnet

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::1c5a:b8ac:59f0:4078%en0           7c:d1:c3:15:1a:ab               UHLWI           en0
fe80::3e15:c2ff:fec3:ecc4%en0           3c:15:c2:c3:ec:c4               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#8                          UCI           awdl0
fe80::444e:b5ff:fe10:887a%awdl0         46:4e:b5:10:88:7a               UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
```

The above is mostly meaningless to me, although it looks like something is going on in the `192.168.33` space.

`netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0"` returns no results.

Also, is there any reason I should be concerned about posting the above info publicly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the network perspective the host machine and virtual box still carry a different LAN IPs. You can connect with those IP addresses

Comment: Sounds good, but trying to connect to mongo on my Mac from the VM results in a time-out problem when I try this.

Comment: Were you able to ping the IP and see if any user firewall is running on the VM?