# Reach web-application on host OS from within VirtualBox

Tags: networking, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running an OSX host with an Debian box inside virtual box. How would I be able to reach the guest OS (i.e. web-app on port 3001) from inside my VM?

I tried `ifconfig` from inside my VM, taking that IP and forwarding ports from the settings UI from VirtualBox, but I'm not entirly sure that's the IP of the box from my host OS.

`VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate Myboxname` yields no IP info. I was told this was because I didn't not have guest additions, so I added guest additions to no avail.

I also tried running my web application from `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Still unable to reach from guest.

Also tried using my default gateway with `netstat -rn`, but was unable to reach any sort of response even from my host machine to this IP (and also hangs from within guest machine).

I need to reach my HOST FROM my GUEST. Can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach my host OS IP address simply as the default gateway from within my guest machine.

INSIDE MY HOST: `netstat -rn` gave me the default gateway.

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os), usually the default gateway is `10.0.2.2`.

Port forwarding did not seem to be necessary to reach the HOST from the GUEST.