# How to stop guests seeing servers running on host but still see internet?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, security

I spent a while struggling to find an answer to how to allow a guest Linux OS in VirtualBox to access a server on the host Linux OS. E.g. say I have Apache running in the host, port 80, and start a virtual machine going, and want to test connecting to that server from inside the virtual machine. I found lots of questions asking how to do it the other direction!

It [turns out](https://superuser.com/q/310697/95390) it is always accessible, and I just needed to use the default gateway IP address (e.g. run `netstat -rn`)

I had switched the server to listen on `0.0.0.0`, assuming I would need to. But when I switched it to listen on just `127.0.0.1`, still the guest OS can see it! I was surprised, and a bit disturbed. I often using a virtual machine to test something I wouldn't run in the host machine, thinking that would be more secure!

Can I configure Virtual Box to say that a guest OS can see the internet (i.e. it can route packets *through* the host), but cannot see anything *on* the host. Configuring iptables on the guest OS wouldn't be a solution - that untrusted software on the guest could theoretically remove it.

Ideally I want this to be the default for all Virtual Box guests, and only when needed I change a setting to allow a guest to access ports on the host.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. If you want that a certain service (that listens to a public IP address, not localhost) is not visible for the guest you have to set-up your firewall on the host to block packets from the virtual machine to that service. The virtualization software can not help you in this case.